# How to use hoverIntent.js plugin with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

I am trying to use jQuery and `hoverIntent.js` on one element called `navbar` as below:

```js
 $(".navbar").hoverIntent({
    over:  $(".navbar").animate({height: "100px"}),
    out:   $(".navbar").animate({height: "50px"})
  });
```

```css
.navbar{background:grey;  height:50px;  width:300px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.hoverintent/1.8.1/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid"> </div>
</nav>
```

I tried both of following methods but none of them work:

```
 $(".navbar").hoverIntent({
    over:  $(".navbar").animate({height: "100px"}),
    out:   $(".navbar").animate({height: "50px"})
  });

$(".navbar").hoverIntent({
function() {
    $(".navbar").animate({height: "100px"});
  }, function() {
    $(".navbar").animate({height: "50px"});
  }
});
```

but it is not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: "Not working" is classic [mcve] territory, since it is the least helpful fault report possible. Voting to close for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in functions...

```js
$(".navbar").hoverIntent({
    over:  function(){ $(".navbar").animate({height: "100px"}) },
    out:   function(){ $(".navbar").animate({height: "50px"}) }
  });
```

```css
.navbar{background:grey;  height:50px;  width:300px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.hoverintent/1.8.1/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid"> </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't send an object, just send two handlers.

```
$(".navbar").hoverIntent(
    function() {$(".navbar").animate({height: "100px"})}, 
    function() {$(".navbar").animate({height: "50px"})}
);
```

Comment: Actually, I wrestled a bear once's answer is more correct.